# MYSQL Union between two large tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

This is probably a simple question for you gurs out there, but my limited knowledge about MYSQL is really showing here:

I have two tables:

```
Table Q with fields id(pk), symbol, timestamp(bigint) and a few data fields
Table T with fields id(pk), symbol, timestamp(bigint) and a few data fields.
```

Table Q has about 800 million rows, table T about 80 million rows.

I want a report for one symbol, where rows from Q and T are mixed in timestamp order. With a row from T, the data fields from Q should be NULL and vice versa.

Can someone please recommend how the query should look? Also, a recommendation on how the index should be constructed would be great.

Have tried a lot of variations on inner, outer joins, union all etc but to no avail.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data and what the result should look like please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a simple UNION ALL (could be union since you indicate that an entry will only exist in only one table or the other anyhow).  Since the tables are the same, should be easy.

I would suggest an index on the table based on your criteria PLUS the date/time field if you want the transactions in a specific order, otherwise an ORDER BY clause can kill your time performance.  If you want more columns, just make sure that each query of the union matches the same order of columns desired and same data types too.

```
select ID, Symbol, timestamp
   from Q
   where symbol = 'something'
UNION ALL
select ID, Symbol, timestamp
   from T
   where symbol = 'something'
```

Again, if you wanted more criteria, you could adjust for each WHERE clause to something like

```
   where symbol = 'something'
     and timestamp between someStartTime and someEndTime
```